# Android Compiling ARM Native Application To x86 (Porting & Houdini)

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, arm, porting

I'm researching how ARM native applications can be compiled on x86 platforms and i've come across 2 topics (Houdini binary translator and porting) that I am having some difficulties with.

These are my questions?
- What is the difference between binary translation and porting
- Are the two both part of compiling an ARM native application to x86

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between binary translation and porting

With binary translation, your app contains ARM NDK binaries, and the device translates the ARM instructions to x86 using `libhoudini`. This results in a smaller APK file, as it only contains fewer NDK binaries. However, the resulting translation is slower than if the app shipped x86 NDK binaries to go along with the ARM ones.

With porting, you explicitly ship x86 NDK binaries along with the ARM ones. This results in a larger APK file but speeds up performance on x86 devices compared to `libhoudini`.

In either case, you should test your code on x86 devices, as well as ARM devices. Also, do not forget that we now have 64-bit ARM and x86 CPUs as well.

Answer (score -2):

First i will try to explain about Houdini. 
Basically Houdini is kind wrapper on x86 , x86_32 architecture. it converts arm library to x86 lib.

porting arm application to x86 you will fell better performance of your application and you devices will perform well like cpu graphics performance

Houdini is wrapper , it converts arm to x86 , if x86 lib is not there in application of system.

Regards,
Deepak